# Can I prevent implicit conversion in parameter to assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

I am implementing a type (`TParameter`) which shall be both a boolean (to indicate if the value is valid) and a data value of arbitrary type.

The idea is that if a method takes a parameter of some type, then I can set it to `false`, to indicate that the value is invalid.

Like this:

```
someVariable = 123;   // use the value 123
someVariable = false; // mark variable as invalid/to-be-ignored
```

A simplified version of my code:

```
template <class T>

class TParameter
{
  public:
    TParameter()
    : m_value(),
      m_valid(false)
    {}

    // assignment operators
    TParameter& operator= (const T& value)
    {
      m_value = value;
      m_valid = true;
      return *this;
    }

    TParameter& operator= (bool valid)
    {
      m_valid = valid;
      return *this;
    }

  private:
    T m_value;
    bool m_valid;
};

  void test()
  {
    TParameter<int16_t> param;

    param = false;
    param = int16_t(123);
    param = 123;
  }
```

When compiling the code I get the error:

> ```
> ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘TParameter<short int>’ and ‘int’)
> ```

The problem is that integer values can be implicitly cast to a `bool`, and therefore the last line in `test()` does not compile.

Is it possible to tell the compiler that `TParameter& operator= (bool valid)` shall only be used if the parameter is a `bool` (i.e. disable implicit cast to `bool`)?

Comment: fwiw `std::optional` does more or less what you are rebuilding

Comment: What if you want to have `T=bool`? (personally I think I'd have `m_valid` set to `true` on assignment and a `reset` or `clear` method to set `m_valid` to `false`). The problem is that you are taking `const T&`, which is not a perfect match with `int16_t` (`T`), so even if you "disable" the other assignment operator it would not work.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 unfortunately I am restricted to an older compiler - C++17 is not available.

Comment: @jdehesa the code was stripped down, so that it only shows the part that is causing issues. The full version does include does include the methods you mention, to havdle the case where T=bool and some other strange cases when T is a more complex type. I just thought it would be nice with a simple syntax for the simple data types.

Comment: if you cannot use `std::optional` you can still look at its interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the 1st overload template, then the 2nd overload will be preferred only when being passed a `bool` (because non-template function is preferred over template under same situation). Otherwise, the template version will be selected because it's an exact match.

```
template <typename X>
TParameter& operator= (const X& value)
{
  m_value = value;
  m_valid = true;
  return *this;
}

TParameter& operator= (bool valid)
{
  m_valid = valid;
  return *this;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/utblxr7XI9x5d0KR)

BTW: In your code, implicit conversion happens when the `operator=` being called; `int` is converted to `int16_t` and then passed to `operator=`. In the code above, the implicit conversion happens inside the `operator=`, i.e. `m_value = value;`.